# LARAVEL 8: ErrorException Undefined index: private

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project, and I have made this form, in order to add some data into db:

```
    <form class="mb-3" method="POST" action="/ask">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="topic" class="BKoodakBold">Question Title</label>
            <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control BSinaBold" id="topic" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="topic" class="BKoodakBold">Question Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" class="form-control BSinaBold" id="comment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <label for="topic" class="BKoodakBold">Question Category</label>
        <select class="form-control BSinaBold" name="category" id="category">
            @foreach(\App\Models\Category::all() as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select></br>
        <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label BKoodakBold">
                <input name="private" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="checkbox" value="on">
                private chat
            </label>
        </div></br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary BJadidBold">Send</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger BJadidBold">Reset</button>
    </form>
```

And at the Controller, I have added these codes:

```
    public function postForm()
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'private' => 'nullable',
            'category' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        Question::create([
            'title' => $validate_data['title'],
            'body' => $validate_data['body'],
            'private' => $validate_data['private'],
            'category' => $validate_data['category']
        ]);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Now the problem, if I UNCHECKED the `private chat` checkbox, I get this as error:

**ErrorException
Undefined index: private**

However, if I checked it, the form will be submitted successfully.

So what is your idea on this, how can I fix this issue?

> Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('private');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the Question migration schema you have written ?

Comment: @MetByrdy Sure, I added it, please check it out, thanks.

Comment: I think it's sending null values, but you don't allow to save them

Comment: private field in table questions should be nullable and just call Question::create($validate_data);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('private')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Designate that the column allows NULL values

Comment: I rollbacked the table and re-make it but still gets the error. It is showing me this line as error: `'private' => $validate_data['private'],`

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled 
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize

Comment: you can also post if the error is different :)

Comment: Just like @AnuratChapanond said, private field in table questions should be nullable and just call `Question::create($validate_data);`.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
 Arr::get($validate_data, 'private', 0)
```

or

```
 $request->input('private', 0)
```

Note that with Arr::get() you don't need to specify third argument, since it is false by default. In cases like this, you should use some helpers with defult value. I imagine that this will work also:

```
'private' => $validate_data['private'] ?? false
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this question is solved, would you mind please check out my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411766/laravel-8-undefined-variable-questions/

Answer (score 0):

```
if your private checkbox not nullable() use $table->string('private');

'private' => 'required',

then uncheck private so your value will be add 'off' if it is checked it will be store 'on'.

if($request->get('private') == null){
            $private= off;
        }
        else{
            $private= request('private');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this question is solved, would you mind please check out my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66411766/laravel-8-undefined-variable-questions/