# Laravel 8: Undefined variable: questions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop to my project.

Now I want to show some data from the DB, so I coded this in the Controller:

```
use App\Models\Question;
public function index()
{
    questions = Question::all();
    return view('home', compact('questions'));
}
```

Then at the view `home.blade.php`, I added this:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
        <h3 class="h5 mb-0"><a href="#0" class="text-uppercase">{{ $question->title }}</a></h3>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

But now I get this as error:

**ErrorException
Undefined variable: questions (View: home.blade.php)**

So what's going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share your idea and suggestion about this...

And here is also `web.php` route, if you want to take a look at:

```
Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `questions` to `$questions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $questions = Question::all();
return view('home', compact('questions'));
```

You Forgot the $ before the var name.

Comment: Try to dd the variable, and see what is the result.
Ex : dd($questions);

Answer (score 0):

you can not include $ in your variable please add

```
$questions = Question::all();

return view('home', compact('questions'));
```

Another option you can use

```
return view('home')->with('questions', $questions);
```

Answer (score 0):

> this is your logic code

```
$questions = Question::all();

return view('home', compact('questions'));
```

> and view code also be like this that it handle exception

```
  @if(isset($questions))
    @foreach($questions as $question)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <h3 class="h5 mb-0"><a href="#0" class="text-uppercase">{{ $question->title }}</a></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```